# MySQL JOIN multiple query result to 1 result set

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, group-by

I want to join multiple result sets to 1 result on one key.

There is 3 tables ( i add here only relevant records):

```
Project table : | id | project |

File table    : | id | project_id |

Approved table: | file_id | dep1_date | dep2_date | dep3_date |
```

The departments default is a date string: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
The first query is:

```
SELECT project.project, 
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(approved.dep1_date,file.uploaded_datetime)))) as dep1_avg
FROM APPROVED
LEFT JOIN file on file.id = approved.file_id
LEFT JOIN project on project.id=file.project_id
WHERE approved.dep1_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY project.project
```

It will give me the approval times average groupped as projects etc.:

```
Project    Dep1_avg
project1   01:03:02
project2   04:14:03
project3   00:07:56
...
```

I want to run this query 2 more times with dep2 and dep3_date too, and attach to the first result set, but contains different WHERE statament (approved.dep2_date, approved.dep3_date).

How can it be done to look the table this?

```
Project    Dep1_avg Dep2_avg Dep3_avg
project1   01:03:02          04:23:11
project2   04:14:03 11:33:44
project3   00:07:56 00:13:43 32:24:17
...
```

The 2 more result is grupped same as the first query(by projects), and if no approval on one project for etc Dep2 or Dep3 it shouls be NULL or empty

What the query looks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do it with multiple where statements, but rather select whether or not to include a row into the AVG inside the select itself. (It *could* be done with multiple where statements by doing a number of subqueries, but that would probably not be very efficient.

```
SELECT project.project, 
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(IF( approved.dep1_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(approved.dep1_date,file.uploaded_datetime), NULL))) as dep1_avg
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(IF( approved.dep2_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(approved.dep2_date,file.uploaded_datetime), NULL))) as dep2_avg
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(IF( approved.dep3_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(approved.dep3_date,file.uploaded_datetime), NULL))) as dep3_avg
FROM APPROVED
LEFT JOIN file on file.id = approved.file_id
LEFT JOIN project on project.id=file.project_id
GROUP BY project.project
```

Values that are NULL aren't included in a diff, so this basically just checks if the value shouldn't be included, and in that cases swaps it out for a NULL, which will be ignored. This lets you scrap the whole WHERE clause.

Comment: Great answer, thx!, It solved my problem. However you have 2 errors in the above code, missing closing `)` after TIME_TO_SEC statements and commas `,` after SET_TO_TIME rows. Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT project.project, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IF(approved.dep1_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIMEDIFF(a.dep1_date, f.uploaded_datetime), NULL)))) AS dep1_avg, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IF(approved.dep2_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIMEDIFF(a.dep2_date, f.uploaded_datetime), NULL)))) AS dep2_avg, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IF(approved.dep3_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIMEDIFF(a.dep3_date, f.uploaded_datetime), NULL)))) AS dep3_avg
FROM APPROVED a
LEFT JOIN `file` f ON f.id = a.file_id
LEFT JOIN project p ON p.id = f.project_id
GROUP BY p.project;
```

Comment: If you use the number 0 it will still change the average number. You should use a NULL instead.